# Create a simple math calculator +-/* accepting only Chinese characters

Tags: math, popularity-contest

**The task:**
Build a calculator that takes a simple math equation in Chinese and outputs the correct answer(To the equation from the users input) in Chinese.

---

**Scope:**

- Any programming language can be used.
- Input must be in Chinese otherwise an error message will be displayed .
- Output must be in Chinese.
- Only input and output of whole numbers between 0-999 will be in scope (this is meant to be a simple calcaulation).
- The full original input must be included prior to equals then the answer.
- Display answer with no decimal points.
- Long number form output is mandatory.
- Input must accept Long number form, inclusion of short form is optional.

**Sample input/output:**

> 二乘以八  (2*8)
>   二乘以八等于十六 (2*8=16)

**Cheat Sheet:**

> 零 or 〇 → 0 (either form or both, you choose)
>   一 → 1
>   二 → 2
>   三 → 3
>   四 → 4
>   五 → 5
>   六 → 6
>   七 → 7
>   八 → 8
>   九 → 9
>   十 → 10
>   百 → 100
>   加 → + Operator
>   减 → - Operator
>   乘以 → * Operator
>   除以 → / Operator
>   等于 → = Operator
>
> Chinese numbering is basic 333 is just 3 100 3 10 3 三百三十三 only exception is 十 where you don't need 一十 to say 10 (but you might to), but you do need 一百 to say 100 (i.e., can't say just 百).

Useful link: http://www.mandarintools.com/numbers.html

If you can't see the chinese symbols, [you may see them here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkmPR.png).

Get creative and happy coding!

Comment: Can I use 零 for zero? Otherwise how could I write 101 (一百零一)?

Comment: @Victor 一百〇一 :) Cheat sheet updated

Comment: Is it 〇 as in your comment or 零 as in the cheat sheet?

Comment: Either or, it's a cheat sheet not a definitive guide :) both 零 and 〇 are technically Chinese for zero. You can include capital numbers if you really want to :)

Comment: you said "you don't need 一十to say 10" does this mean that it is not acceptable to use it?

Comment: Fine to use either way

Comment: @user689 I edited the question to make it clear about 一十.

Comment: Do you use 一百十六 or 一百一十六 for 116? Or can it be both?

Comment: @JoeZ. I think that it must be 一百一十六. The 十 without the 一 prefix should be used only in the start of the number. But I can't say that I am sure about this.

Comment: @Victor That would be 一百十六.

Comment: The interesting thing about this question is that there are two ways of saying numbers in Mandarin: this way, and listing off the numerals. Just like how in English we often say two two five six for `2256`, in Mandarin, that can be said as 二二五六

Comment: @Quincunx Quoting http://www.mandarintools.com/numbers.html : [[*One-hundred is "one hundred". One-hundred and one is "one hundred zero one". One hundred and eleven is "one hundred one ten one". Notice that for eleven alone, you only need "ten one" and not "one ten one", but when used in a larger number (such as 111), you must add the extra "one".*]]

Comment: @Victor refering to my first comment, I just told you how it would *normally* be said. If you paste that into your tool, you'll see that it comes out the same.

Comment: @quincunx that is true for room numbers, building numbers, ect... but never seen the shorthand used in math

Comment: @50-3 I haven't heard it used much for math, mainly for telephone numbers, room numbers, etc. However, according to http://www.mandarintools.com/numbers.html, 987654321 is 九億八千七百六十五萬四千三百二十一. If I wanted to say that, I'd definitely say 九八七六五四三二一 and make sure that the listeners understand from the context that it is a number.

Comment: @50-3 You should specify if we should choose to handle the short or the long form or both, or if the long form is obligatory and the short optional (I recommend this), or if both are obligatory.

Answer (score 5):

## Java

It parses the equation as a context-free language, using these productions for that:

```
U1 = [一-九]                 (i.e. [1-9])
D1 = U1 十 U1?
DO = U1? 十 U1?
CDN = 〇 U1 | D1
C1 = U1 百 CDN?
F = C1 | DO | U1 | 〇
F2 = 負? F
OP = 加 | 减 | 乘以 | 除以    (i.e., + | - | * | / )
EQ = F2 (OP F2)*
```

The `DO` and `D1` productions are handled in the same method, diferentiated by a parameter. The other productions take one method each. The `EQ` is the grammar main symbol. Before starting the parse, it replaces 零 for 〇, so it need to handle just 〇 after that.

The 負 is for negative numbers. It can handle numbers from -999 to 999 (or 負九百九十九 to 九百九十九).

Further, to make it much more chinese, all the identifiers are in chinese. The only exception is the class name (using international characters there may cause problems) that is a chinese name transliterated to latin characters.

For the input I had to use a `JOptionPane`. Sorry for that, but I had trouble about encodings using other input methods. If you don't like this method of input, you can use the `解方程` method directly, it takes the input formula and produce the output equation (or error message).

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ZhongguoJisuanQi {

    private final String 文字输入;
    private int 源指数;

    public ZhongguoJisuanQi(String 文字输入) {
        this.文字输入 = 文字输入.replace("零", "〇");
        this.源指数 = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String... 参数) {
        String 方程 = 解方程(读取文本行());
        System.out.println(方程);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 方程, "答案是", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    private static String 读取文本行() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "输入数学公式", "输入数学公式", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }

    public static String 解方程(String 数学公式) {
        if (数学公式 == null) return "错误：给定的数学公式的格式不正确。";
        ZhongguoJisuanQi 计算器 = new ZhongguoJisuanQi(数学公式);
        Integer 结果 = 计算器.解析并解决了式();
        if (结果 == null) return "错误：给定的数学公式的格式不正确。";
        return 数学公式 + "等于" + 整数转换为文本(结果);
    }

    private boolean 找到字符(char 字符, int 指数) {
        return 指数 < 文字输入.length() && 文字输入.charAt(指数) == 字符;
    }

    private Integer 解析生产一() {
        int 数 = "一二三四五六七八九".indexOf(文字输入.charAt(源指数));
        if (数 == -1) return null;
        源指数++;
        return 数 + 1;
    }

    private Integer 解析生产十(boolean 必须带有前缀) {
        int 原始来源索引 = 源指数;
        Integer 第一个数字 = 解析生产一();
        if (第一个数字 == null && 必须带有前缀) return null;
        if (!找到字符('十', 源指数)) {
            源指数 = 原始来源索引;
            return null;
        }
        源指数++;
        Integer 第二个数字 = 解析生产一();
        return (第一个数字 == null ? 1 : 第一个数字) * 10 + (第二个数字 == null ? 0 : 第二个数字);
    }

    private Integer 解析生产或零十() {
        int 原始来源索引 = 源指数;
        if (找到字符('〇', 源指数)) {
            源指数++;
            Integer 数 = 解析生产一();
            if (数 == null) {
                源指数 = 原始来源索引;
                return null;
            }
            return 数;
        }
        return 解析生产十(true);
    }

    private Integer 解析生产百() {
        int 原始来源索引 = 源指数;
        Integer 第一个数字 = 解析生产一();
        if (第一个数字 == null) return null;
        if (!找到字符('百', 源指数)) {
            源指数 = 原始来源索引;
            return null;
        }
        源指数++;
        Integer 第二个数字 = 解析生产或零十();
        return 第一个数字 * 100 + (第二个数字 == null ? 0 : 第二个数字);
    }

    private Integer 解析生产数无符号() {
        Integer 数 = 解析生产百();
        if (数 != null) return 数;
        数 = 解析生产十(false);
        if (数 != null) return 数;
        数 = 解析生产一();
        if (数 != null) return 数;
        if (找到字符('〇', 源指数)) {
            源指数++;
            return 0;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Integer 解析该生产号() {
        boolean 负 = false;
        if (找到字符('負', 源指数)) {
            源指数++;
            负 = true;
        }
        Integer 数 = 解析生产数无符号();
        return 数 == null ? null : 负 ? -数 : 数;
    }

    private String 解析算术运算符() {
        if (找到字符('加', 源指数)) { 源指数++; return "加"; }
        if (找到字符('减', 源指数)) { 源指数++; return "减"; }
        if (找到字符('乘', 源指数) && 找到字符('以', 源指数 + 1)) { 源指数 += 2; return "乘以"; }
        if (找到字符('除', 源指数) && 找到字符('以', 源指数 + 1)) { 源指数 += 2; return "除以"; }
        return null;
    }

    public Integer 解析并解决了式() {
        Integer 第一个数字 = 解析该生产号();
        while (true) {
            String 算术运算符 = 解析算术运算符();
            if (算术运算符 == null) return 源指数 == 文字输入.length() ? 第一个数字 : null;
            Integer 第二个数字 = 解析该生产号();
            if (第二个数字 == null) return null;
            switch (算术运算符) {
                case "加": 第一个数字 += 第二个数字; break;
                case "减": 第一个数字 -= 第二个数字; break;
                case "乘以": 第一个数字 *= 第二个数字; break;
                case "除以": 第一个数字 /= 第二个数字; break;
                default: throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }
    }

    private static String 整数转换为文本(int 参数) {
        if (参数 == 0) return "〇";
        StringBuilder 字符串生成器 = new StringBuilder(7);
        int 数 = 参数;
        if (数 < 0) {
            字符串生成器.append("負");
            数 = -数;
        }
        if (数 >= 1000) return null;
        if (数 >= 100) {
            字符串生成器.append("〇一二三四五六七八九".charAt(数 / 100)).append("百");
            数 %= 100;
            if (数 >= 1 && 数 <= 9) 字符串生成器.append("〇");
            if (数 >= 10 && 数 <= 19) 字符串生成器.append("一");
        }
        if (数 >= 20) 字符串生成器.append("〇一二三四五六七八九".charAt(数 / 10));
        if (数 >= 10) 字符串生成器.append("十");
        数 %= 10;
        字符串生成器.append("〇一二三四五六七八九".charAt(数));
        return 字符串生成器.toString();
    }
}
```

Compile with:

```
javac -encoding UTF8 ZhongguoJisuanQi.java
```

Run with:

```
java ZhongguoJisuanQi
```

Cheat sheet for identifiers names, accordingly to google translator:

```
(english original text) -> (chinese text) -> (english text back from chinese)
chinese calculator -> 中国计算器 (Zhōngguó jìsuàn qì) -> china calculator
text input -> 文字输入 -> text input
source index -> 源指数 -> source index
original source index -> 原始来源索引 -> original source index
Enter the mathematical formula -> 输入数学公式 -> Enter mathematical formulas
mathematical formula -> 数学公式 -> mathematical formulas
Error: The given mathematical formula is malformed. -> 错误：给定的数学公式的格式不正确。 -> Error: The given mathematical formula is not correct.
character -> 字符 -> character
read a text line -> 读取文本行 -> read a line of text
arguments -> 参数 -> parameter
equation -> 方程 -> equation
index -> 指数 -> index
find character at -> 找到字符 -> find characters
parse the production -> 解析生产 -> resolve the production
parse the production or zero -> 解析生产或零 -> resolve the production or zero
parse the production number -> 解析该生产号 -> resolve the production number
parse the production number without sign -> 解析生产数无符号 -> resolve production unsigned
parse and solve the formula -> 解析并解决了式 -> parse and resolve the formula
parse an arithmetic operator -> 解析算术运算符 -> parsing arithmetic operators
arithmetic operator -> 算术运算符 -> arithmetic operators
must be prefixed -> 必须带有前缀 -> must be prefixed with
calculator -> 计算器 -> calculators
solve the equation -> 解方程 -> solving equations
result -> 结果 -> result
number -> 数 -> number
minus -> 负 -> minus
first number -> 第一个数字 -> the first number
second number -> 第二个数字 -> second number
string builder -> 字符串生成器 -> string builder
convert integer to text -> 整数转换为文本 -> integer is converted to text
the answer is -> 答案是 -> the answer is
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell

Here is a solution in Haskell with custom made parser combinators. No library is required, all pure functional power. :)

The grammar in the middle of the file describes the structure of the expressions that will be parsed. The grammar itself is the parser, and it is build from terminal parsers, with parser combinators to put them in sequence (`<:>`,`<::>`) or as alternatives (`|||`). Each of the terminal parsers parses a certain string or character, such as an operator or a digit. The evaluation combinator (`==>`) then transforms and calculates the expression.

Some inspiration I found 
[in this blog](http://alephnullplex.appspot.com/blog/view/2010/01/12/lbach-1-introduction), but mainly I learned this when I worked with a DSL embedded in Haskell that uses the same approach ([ADP, Algebraic Dynamic Programming](http://bibiserv.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/adp/), I wrote a typechecker for it), here we can even solve optimization problems with dynamic programming!
Also there is a nice paper by G.Hutton about parsing with combinators in Haskell.

This was a really fun problem, thanks for suggesting it!

The `calc_own_combi.hs` file:

```
type Parser a = String -> Maybe (a, String) 

dict = [('零', 0) ,('〇', 0) ,('一', 1) ,('二', 2) ,('三', 3) ,('四', 4) ,('五', 5) ,('六', 6) ,('七', 7) ,('八', 8) ,('九', 9), ('十',10), ('百',100)]

-- parse 1 character
char :: Parser Char
char [] = Nothing
char (x:xs) = Just(x, xs)

-- parse a chinese digit
cndigit :: Parser Char
cndigit = char <== isCNdigit
  where isCNdigit c = elem c $ map fst dict

-- parse a string literal
literal :: String -> Parser String
literal s [] = Nothing
literal s xs = if (head==s) then Just(head, tail)
                            else Just("", xs)
  where (head,tail) = splitAt (length s) xs 

-- parse and evaluate the following terminal symbols
digit = cndigit ==> cnDigitToInt
  where cnDigitToInt d = head [snd x | x <- dict, fst x==d]
add  = literal "加"   ==> (\_ -> (+))
subt = literal "减"   ==> (\_ -> (-))
mult = literal "乘以" ==> (\_ -> (*))
divi = literal "除以" ==> (\_ -> div)
tens = literal "十"   ==> (\_ -> t)
  where t a b = a * 10 + b
hndrds = literal "百" ==> (\_ -> h)
  where h a b = a * 100 + b

-- inject a 1 into the parse in case people underspecify tens
inject1 :: Parser Integer
inject1 s = Just (1, s)

-- the grammar
expression = number <:> add  <::> number |||
             number <:> subt <::> number |||
             number <:> mult <::> number |||
             number <:> divi <::> number |||
             number
number = digit <:> (hndrds <::> (digit <:> tens <::> digit)) |||
         digit <:> tens <::> digit |||
         digit |||
         inject1 <:> tens <::> digit -- inject 1 to reuse the function

-- run the calculator as a repl
main = putStrLn "type ':q' to quit." >> repl
 where 
  repl = do
         input <- getLine
         let result = printNum $ eval input
         if ((== ":q") input)
           then return ()
           else putStrLn (input ++ "等于" ++ result) >> repl

-- call the grammar to parse and evaluate
eval s = case expression s of
   Just (n,[]) -> n
   Just (n,xs) -> error $ "Could not parse input, got stuck on "++xs
   Nothing -> error $ "Could not parse input at all "++s

-- reencode a number into chinese
printNum x = h' ++ t' ++ o
 where o  = if ((h'/="" || t'/="") && tRest == 0) then "" else [intToCNDigit tRest] 
       h' = printDigit h "百"
       t' = printDigit t "十"
       printDigit d c | d==0 = ""
                      | d==1 && c=="百" = '一':c
                      | d==1 = c
                      | otherwise = intToCNDigit d:c
       (t, tRest) = divMod hRest 10
       (h, hRest) = divMod x 100
       intToCNDigit d =  head [fst x | x <- dict, snd x==d]

-- the combinators:

-- return the result of the parser only if
-- it also satisfies the given predicate - like `with` in ADP
infix 7 <== 
(<==) :: Parser a -> (a -> Bool) -> Parser a 
(m <== p) s = case m s of 
        Nothing     -> Nothing 
        Just(a,s)  -> if p a then Just(a,s) else Nothing

-- alternative/or combinator
infixl 3 |||
(|||) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a 
(m ||| n) s = case m s of 
    Nothing -> n s 
    ms -> ms

-- next/sequence combinator
-- reverse polish notation needs just this:
-- testRPExp = digit <:> (digit <:> add)
infixl 6 <:>
(<:>) :: Parser a -> Parser (a -> b) -> Parser b
(m <:> n) s = case m s of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (a, s') -> case n s' of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just (b, s2) -> Just (b a, s2)

-- next/sequence combinator, right side
-- infix notation needs this second combinator:
-- testExp = digit <:> add <::> digit
infixl 5 <::>
(<::>) :: Parser (a->b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
(m <::> n) s = case m s of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (a, s') -> case n s' of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just (b, s2) -> Just (a b, s2)

-- evaluate a parse result :)
infixl 5 ==>
(==>) :: Parser a -> (a -> b) -> Parser b
(m ==> n) s = case m s of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (a, s') -> Just (n a, s')
```

Running it:

```
┌─[linse@yolocat]─[~/test]
└──╼ ghc -o calc calc_own_combi.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( own_combi.hs, own_combi.o )
Linking calc ...
┌─[linse@yolocat]─[~/test]
└──╼ ./calc
type ':q' to quit.
二乘以八
二乘以八等于十六
:q
```

Comment: That's a cool command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

## Smalltalk (Smalltalk/X)

using a [packrat parser](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/helvetia/petitparser) (just a q&d hack, I guess, this could be done better, especially the number parsing; I was not 100% sure, when it is allowed to leave out zeros...).
Also, I don't understand what "零 or 〇 → 0" means; does it mean "it must support both" or "I can choose to support either"?
Anyway, if required, the d0 rule could be changed easily.
For readability, the code is not golfified.

```
"/ parsing digits
d0 := ($零 asParser ==> [:c|0]).
d1 := ($一 asParser ==> [:c|1]).   
d2 := ($二 asParser ==> [:c|2]).   
d3 := ($三 asParser ==> [:c|3]).   
d4 := ($四 asParser ==> [:c|4]).   
d5 := ($五 asParser ==> [:c|5]).   
d6 := ($六 asParser ==> [:c|6]).   
d7 := ($七 asParser ==> [:c|7]).   
d8 := ($八 asParser ==> [:c|8]).   
d9 := ($九 asParser ==> [:c|9]).
t:= $十 asParser.  
h:= $百 asParser.  
d := d1|d2|d3|d4|d5|d6|d7|d8|d9.
"/ parsing numbers
n :=
    ((d,h,d,t,d) ==> [:a| (a first*100)+(a third *10)+a fifth])
    / ((d,h,d,t) ==> [:a| (a first*100)+(a third *10)])
    / ((d,h,d) ==> [:a| (a first*100)+(a third)])
    / ((d,h) ==> [:a| a first*100])
    / ((d,t,d) ==> [:a| (a first*10)+(a third)])
    / ((d,t) ==> [:a| a first*10])
    / ((t,d) ==> [:a| a second+10])
    / d0 
    / d 
    / (t ==> [:c|10])
    .
"/ operators
A:= ($加 asParser)==>[:c|#+].
S:= ($减 asParser)==>[:c|#-].
M := ($乘 asParser , $以 asParser)==>[:c|#*].
D:= ($除 asParser , $以 asParser)==>[:c|#/].

"/ times and quotient
T:= ((n,M,T) ==>[:a|(a first * a third)])
   / ((n,D,T) ==>[:a|(a first / a third)])
   / n
   .

"/ sum and difference
E:=((T,A,E) ==>[:n|(n first + n third)])
   / ((T,S,E) ==>[:n|(n first - n third)])
   / T
   .

"/ printing (number->string)
di:= #( $一 $二 $三 $四 $五 $六 $七 $八 $九).
P:=[:n| 
  n>=100 
    ifTrue:[ (di at:(n//100)),$百,(P value:(n\\100)) ]
    ifFalse:[
      n>20 
        ifTrue:[ (di at:(n//10)),$十,(P value:(n\\10)) ]
        ifFalse:[ 
          n>10 
            ifTrue:[$十,(P value:(n\\10))]
            ifFalse:[
              n==10 
                ifTrue:[$十]
                ifFalse:[
                  n==0 
                    ifTrue:[$零] 
                    ifFalse:[(di at:n) ]]]]]].
"/ evaluate an expression and return numeric value
p:= (E end) ==> P.

"/ the calculator, parse, concatenate input,EQ,number string
calc:=[:s | s,'等于',(p parse:s)].
```

usage:

```
calc value:'二乘以八'.
```

-> '二乘以八等于十六'

Comment: The "零 or 〇 → 0" is actually underspecified. As originally posted, the question missed the zero entirely (and numbers like "一百零一" (101) were impossible). After that, the OP inserted 零 in the question, but did a comment with 〇. So I edited the question adding both, but which one to use is not clear. Anyway, since this is popularity-contest, it probably does not matter too much anyway, but you would be safer if you allow both forms.

Comment: Well, I decided to edit the question and pu it as *零 or 〇 → 0 (either form or both, you choose)*, so nobody will have trouble with this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried writing this one in python:

```
import compiler
# encoding: utf-8

# python chinese calculator,

c2e = {('1','一'),('2','二'),('3','三'),('4','四'),('5','五'),('6','六'),('7','七'),('8','八'),('9','九'),('0','零')}

def tochi(eq):
    for en,ch in c2e:
        eq.replace(en,ch)
    return eq

def toen(eq):
    for en,ch in c2e:
        eq.replace(ch,en)
    return eq

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        eqin = raw_input('Equation with chinese numbers: ')
        eqin = toen(eqin)
        eqout = compiler.parse(eqin)
        eqout = tochi(eqout)
        print eqout
```

Comment: Try adding a `# encoding: utf-8` line at the start

Comment: Actually, just `# coding=utf-8` is enough. Python doesn't mind as long as the first or second line [matches](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)  `coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)`. On a side note, I recommend using Python 3 for new projects when possible. YMMV.

Comment: Also, it's a **really** bad idea to use `input()` in Python 2. It's **not** meant for numerical input, it's meant for evaluating Python code. Consider using `raw_input()` and parsing manually instead. (In Python 3, `input()` is equivalent to Python 2's `raw_input()`, and you use `eval(input())` for the old functionality.)

Comment: Erm, I don't see where do you handle the chinese operators. Further, if I input a number like 十一 or 百, I don't think that it will do the right thing.

Comment: Once i saw the whole rules, i didnt feel like implementing that part